# ExcelDataReader wrong decimal number (non formatted)

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I've been using `ExcelDataReader` to get some .xlsx files and convert them to DataSet with the `AsDataSet()` method.

But, I have a big problem. Inside a column on Excel we have a value '2061,95' (with ',' as decimal separator, because I'm from Brazil).

I renamed the .xlsx to .zip and extracted the files and the value is '2061.94899999'.

But inside my software there is a rule that a number can be with only 2 decimal places and I can't use round.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hmm? Why can't you use round?

Comment: So do you want it truncated, or rounded in some way that doesn't "use round"?

Comment: @lc because, its a column that store monetary values.

Comment: So what's the actual value in Excel?  If you select the cell what is shown in the formula bar: 2061.95 or 2061.9489999 ?  If the stored value in Excel has more than two decimal places, and you're only allowing two, then you *have* to round (or truncate).

Comment: @TimWilliams, in the formula bar the value is 2061.95, but inside the software have a business rules that if a value came with more then 2 decimal places, the process of importation will be aborted, and doing the round i will loose the 'original' value.

Comment: Can you add more detail around "extracted the files and the value is" - how exactly are you getting the value of 2061.9489999?

Comment: Could you resolve this issue? I can also not read decimal values comma separated like `123,45` (they are interpreted as `12345`)...